# What is the most efficient way to define a Loop until function?

Tags: programming, procedural-programming, iteration

*Mathematica* has the `While` function which is very convenient when we need to process some code until the attainment of a certain state (identified with a condition). Personally, I also like very much the **Loop-Until** approach.

An advantage of the **Loop** *body* **Until** *condition* is that the body being performed first, it is not necessary to set initial values to the variables being tested in *condition*. In `While`, all the variables must be set so that the preliminary test can return a value.

I have this definition below but would like to know if there are more efficient ways to define a **Loop**.

```
Loop[body_, test_] := Block[{}, body; While[! test, body]]
SetAttributes[Loop, HoldAll]
```

**Edit**

With the nice comments of everyone, I updated the code so that a *MaxIterations* option can be given, and *usage* and *error* messages are provided:

```
Unprotect[Loop];
Loop::usage = "Loop[body, test] performs body then verify test until test returns True. Loop[body, test, MaxIterations-> i] sets a maximal number of iterations (default infinity).";
Loop::maxiter = "Maxiterations `1` reached. Aborting...";
Loop[body_, test_, opt___] := Block[
  {res, currenti = 1, maxi = MaxIterations /. {opt} /. Options[Loop]},
  body;
  While[(!test) && (currenti<maxi), 
    res = body; 
    If[maxi == ++currenti, Message[Loop::maxiter, currenti]; Abort[]]
  ];
  res
  ]
SetAttributes[Loop, HoldAll]
Options[Loop] = {MaxIterations -> Infinity};
Protect[Loop];
```

Here are two examples

```
n = 1;
Loop[Print[n]; ++n, n > 4]
n = 1;
Loop[Print[n]; ++n, n > 4, MaxIterations -> 2]
```

Comment: I updated the answer.

Comment: I'll just add the obligatory reference: [Alternatives to procedural loops and iterating over lists in Mathematica](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/7924/27951).

Comment: Another option is to set a boolean flag (OMG!) before you enter the loop, and then turn the flag off inside the loop when condition is met. As in `keepRunning = True; While[keepRunning, ...... If[condition,keepRunning=False]]`.  Notice there is no no need to do `Break[]` now.  This will run one time at least.  This is how we used to program in the good old days :)

Comment: @Nasser: yes, indeed, the Loop structure was very popular with languages such as Pascal. I also find it more intuitive than the **While**. Your version is neat as well. What about performance in terms of computation times?

Comment: There is [Until in the Wolfram Function Repository](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/Until)

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Well, well, after 33 years, Wolfram decided to add this function in Mathematica 11.3! Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I tend to use

```
While[True,
  body;
  If[condition, Break[]]
]
```

but what you show is equally good. This is just an alternative.

Try to avoid procedural loops in Mathematica when you can.

This is of course not always possible, but we can define a functional equivalent of the concept. In IGraph/M, I have a utility function called `IGTryUntil`. `IGTryUntil[cond][x]` will keep evaluating `x` until `cond[x]` becomes `True`, then it returns `x`. One of the main use cases is rejection sampling: generate random objects until they satisfy a condition. For example, a random connected graph: `IGTryUntil[ConnectedGraphQ][RandomGraph[{20,20}]]`.

If you are going to create a custom function for this, it does not matter that much if the implementation is not simple. It's the usage of the function that should be simple. You can see the implementation of `IGTryUntil` here:

https://github.com/szhorvat/IGraphM/blob/a65dceb5ab1135e77b496a05888aa94787d3be91/IGraphM/Utilities.m#L513

Comment: "Try to avoid procedural loops..." Good point, we might use `Loop[body_, test_] := 
 Block[{res}, body; While[! test, res = body]; res]`

Comment: Both answers were equally usefull. I had to make a choice...

Answer (score 10):

Here's a simpler version:

```
SetAttributes[Until,HoldAll]
Until[body_, test_] := While[body; !test]
```

Comment: There should be a negation to `test` but yes, very elegant!

Comment: @DenisCousineau Thanks, I fixed the bug. However, did you want to use `Until[body, test]` or `Until[test, body]`?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by Denis Cousineau in his comment, `Until` is now part of the language (since V 13.1)

```
n = 1; list = {}; 
Until[n > 4, AppendTo[list, n++]
list
```

{1, 2, 3, 4}

This does the same as Carl Woll's answer with switched arguments:

```
SetAttributes[until, HoldAll]
until[test_, body_] := While[body; ! test]

n = 1; list = {}; 
until[n > 4, AppendTo[list, n++]]
list
```

{1, 2, 3, 4}